# is this grammatically correct as it is using past as well as present tense in the same sentence

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> And when I fell hard
>   you took a step back
>   Without me, without me, without me
>
> And he's long gone
>   when he's next to me
>   And I realize the blame is on me
>   ~[Taylor Swift](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/t/taylor+swift/i+knew+you+were+trouble_21045032.html)

Comment: Please see the notes on your other question before asking additional questions.

Comment: sorry for that but can you please answer me as is it correct or not

Comment: No. Because you've not really asked a question. As I've noted on your other question, these are **song lyrics** which are not required to follow conventional grammar rules.

Comment: But, the only reason I know that is because I googled them... you need to add more information to your question if you want us to answer it. Please see the "[Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)" post to improve your question content so that it is more clear.

Comment: ohk thanks catija for your answer as i was quite confused as in this sentence 'fell' as well as 'is' is used even 'took' also

Comment: If you have particular parts of the song you don't understand, you need to point them out in the question and ask about them specifically. Use the **edit** button to make changes to your question and to add more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be treated as a single sentence, but as two different sentences. In the first the singer narrates past events in the past tense; in the second she tells the present outcome of those events in the present tense.

Note the marked change in the melody between the first "sentence" and the second; and note that the entire song (and its spoken intro) moves back and forth between past and present.